# Booting into Internet Recovery after erasing OS

Tags: macos, mac, wifi, recovery

I'm in a situation that I put myself in accidentally. So I needed to erase the OS and put a new one using Internet Recovery, first steps I did well there's no more OS, next quest is to put the OS back in, using "Reinstall OS X" button. Here comes the problem, it says "You need to have internet connection to do it"(something like that). If I reboot the computer to connect the cable(I need to transport it to the other room), can I go back to Internet Recovery mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connect the Ethernet cable, reboot and press cmd-r or alt-cmd-r again while booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just connect it to a cable and re-enter the Recovery Mode (press <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> after power-on, see: [Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) for boot keys); normally Recovery will now see a connection to the Internet – if not, do you have a DHCP server running on the router?